# Tracking data document change in Couchbase

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, couchbase, nosql

i'm stuck at Track changes of Couchbase document. I need to use it to migrate data to another system. I'm already read at couchabse Api but found nothing.
When the action insert/update document data in couchbase, the couchbase save the track change version and i can not get the track chage version lis.
I'm trying to get a track changed list of my current data bucket. But i find no hope find a solution for that. 
Any help much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you give a more specific description of your problem? What you are trying to do, what you have already tried etc?

Comment: Tks for reply, i'm trying to get a track changed list of my current data bucket. But i find no hope find a solution for that.

Comment: I suggest you update the question. As it is it's not clear what's being asked and is in danger of being closed.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are searching(trying to implement) something like this http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-elastic-search/ (but different storage instead elasticsearch)

take look @ TAP protocol http://www.couchbase.com/wiki/display/couchbase/TAP+Protocol